# Increase Haddop_HEAPSIZE in amazon EMR to run job with a few million input files

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, hadoop-streaming

I am running into an issue with my EMR jobs where too many input files throws out of memory errors. Doing some research I think changing the HADOOP_HEAPSIZE config parameter is the solution. Old amazon forums from 2010 say it cannot be done.
can we do that now in 2018??

I run my jobs using the C# API for EMR and normally I set configurations using statements like below.  can I set HADOOP_HEAPSIZE using similar commands.

```
 config.Args.Insert(2, "-D");
             config.Args.Insert(3, "mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress=true");
             config.Args.Insert(4, "-D");
             config.Args.Insert(5, "mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
             config.Args.Insert(6, "-D");
             config.Args.Insert(7, "mapreduce.map.output.compress=true");
             config.Args.Insert(8, "-D");
             config.Args.Insert(9, "mapreduce.task.timeout=18000000");
```

If I need to bootstrap using a file, I can do that too. If someone can show me the contents of the file for the config change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...
I created a shell script to increase the memory size on the master machine (code at the end)...
I run a bootstrap action like this

```
ScriptBootstrapActionConfig bootstrapActionScriptForHeapSizeIncrease = new ScriptBootstrapActionConfig
            {
                Path = "s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/run-if",
                Args = new List<string> { "instance.isMaster=true", "<s3 path to my shell script>" },
            };
```

The shell script code is this

```
#!/bin/bash
SIZE=8192

if ! [ -z $1 ] ; then
  SIZE=$1
fi


echo "HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=${SIZE}" >> /home/hadoop/conf/hadoop-user-env.sh
```

Now I am able to run a EMR job with master machine tye as r3.xlarge and process 31 million input files